# How to remove FBI Moneypak ransomware?

Tags: malware, ms-security-essentials, malware-removal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

My PC just recently got infected with FBI Moneypak ransomware. I'm using MS Security Essentials but it was not able to detect or remove this malware.
There are some guides on the net pertaining to removal of this malware but they are pretty vague and ambiguous.
I need a clear way of how to remove this malware. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer to the canon question http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rebooted the system into Safe Mode and scanned it with MS Security Essentials. That got rid of the ungodly malware.

Answer (score 1):

Even rebooting and scanning from Safe Mode might not remove it.  Many times I've scanned a system, had it find and remove something, rebooted, and scanning after restart found it again.

The best way I've found to remove malware is to do the scan and removal from a CD boot disk, that way the malicious code never gets a chance to run and preserve itself.  I've gotten good results from Windows Defender Offline: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline

Comment: In my case Safe Mode saved the day.